# How Can I apply remark-math, katex to my Elder.js Blog?

Tags: svelte, katex, remarkjs, static-site-generation

May I ask you about my problem? I am trying to apply remark-math to my elder.js blog.
It is not rendered properly. Like this.

**markdown**

```
$$
\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1
h \circ (g \circ f) = (h \circ g) \circ f = h \circ g \circ f
$$
```

**rendered html**

```
<div class="math math-display">
\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1
h \circ (g \circ f) = (h \circ g) \circ f = h \circ g \circ f
</div>
```

**now my blog's link**

https://twinstae.github.io/category-for-functional/

I did followings.

- npm install remark-math remark-katex
- add katex css to head
- add all default pipeline and remarkMath, remarkKatex to elder.config.js

**elder.config.js**

```
plugins: {
  '@elderjs/plugin-markdown': {
    routes: ['blog'],
    remarkPlugins: [
      frontmatter, // 'remark-frontmatter' package
      [extractFrontmatter, { name: 'frontmatter', yaml: yaml.parse }], // 'remark-extract-frontmatter'       and 'yaml' packages.
      remarkSlug, // 'remark-slug' package
      remarkMath,
      remarkKatex,
      remarkHtml, // 'remark-html' package
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

**elder.config.js link**
https://github.com/twinstae/twinstae.github.io/blob/master/elder.config.js

**docs for remark-plugin link**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elderjs/plugin-markdown#remark-plugins

I am trying several plugins orders, searching, reading Elder.js docs again...

Thank you for reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! **rehype**-katex is a plugin for **rehype**

new **elder.config.js**

```
const remarkMath = require('remark-math');
const remark2rehype = require('remark-rehype');
const rehypeKatex = require('rehype-katex');
const rehypeStringify = require('rehype-stringify');

... (default plugins),
remarkMath,
remark2rehype, <- I missed this
rehypeKatex,
rehypeStringify, <- I missed this too
```